# Customizing kernel for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a custom kernel for the Raspberry PI that is really light weight. Basically all it is going to be doing is running Chrome. I am looking through the menuconfig options of what to remove. Which file systems can I remove without it breaking anything? I have attached an image of this screen. I already removed some that I didn't think were necessary (Dnotify support, GFS2 file system support, and OCFS2 file system support). Here is an image of the menuconfig page I am looking at: [Kernel Configuration](http://goo.gl/eJVuTl)

Also, if you have any other suggestions of things that are large in the kernel that can be removed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not exactly specific to the OP but) In general, a good tutorial on building-from-scratch for the R Pi root filesystem and Linux kernel, using the excellent Buildroot tool, can be [found here](http://cellux.github.io/articles/diy-linux-with-buildroot-part-1/).

[Btw, might be useful: I wrote a blog article on "[A KDB / KGDB SESSION ON THE POPULAR RASPBERRY PI EMBEDDED LINUX BOARD](http://kaiwantech.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/a-kdb-kgdb-session-on-the-popular-raspberry-pi-embedded-linux-board/)" which includes this info and more...]

Answer (score 0):

The only filesystem required for your system to function properly is ext4. The can safely remove JFS, XFS, FUSE, and all the network filesystems. You can also remove the support for quotas.